# 400 BadRequest as answer after sendBeacon

Tags: javascript, beacon

I am struggling very hard to find the mistake in my code. I send a beacon with some data to a controller route where the data should be saved in the database. When checking the developer console, I can see that I receive an error (400 bad request) as answer to the beacon request, but when checking if the beacon returns true or false, it's true.

Beacon:

```
var data = new FormData();
                        
data.append('pageid', '{{page::id}}');
data.append('userid', uid);
data.append('language', '{{page::language}}');

navigator.sendBeacon('/time/', data);
```

Controller:

```
$user = $this->security->getUser();
        
        // Check if user is authenticated
        if($user instanceof FrontendUser && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
            // Query
            $sql = '...';
    
            // Execute Query
            $result = $this->connection->fetchAssociative($sql);

            $objResponse = new Response($sql);
        } else {
            // Redirect
            return new RedirectResponse(\Controller::replaceInsertTags('{{page::language}}') . '/');
        }       

        return $objResponse;
```

I already commented out the controller code or just gave a simple string as response back but I always receive this 400 error. Does anyone of you know where I should look for the mistake or has a clue?

Comment: Is the server code you've partially shown above handling `POST` or `GET` (or both)? Beacons use `POST`.

Comment: *"...but when checking if the beacon returns true or false, it's true."* All that means is that the browser successfully queued the data to send, **not** that it was sent successfully: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon#return_values

Comment: Although I guess if it were a method issue, it would be a 405, not a 400. So the question becomes: Does the endpoint accept the `multipart/form-data` content type? (That's the type `Beacon` will use for the `FormData`.)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. The server code is handling the POST request. I just had a look at the request time in the developer console and the first request is the whole time on waiting and every other request is first blocked for about 85ms and then on waiting. So the request isn't send to the server, right?

Comment: Can you explain what you are actually trying to do here? The intended use case for Beacon was to be a replacement in situations where you can't make a "normal" AJAX request, because the user is leaving the current page - Beacon guarantees that the request will be queued for execution despite that, whereas any normal AJAX/fetch request would be cancelled at this point. But since you are talking about _multiple_ requests here, I am wondering if that even actually _is_ your scenario here now ...?

Comment: I am trying to track the time, the user spents in the active window. If he minimize it or tabs out, a request is sent with the time. It worked great for a while but I had to update PHP and the CMS and adapted the code to make it work again but I realized that at some point this error came up.